# Can you use "as + adjective + a/an + noun + as" with plural nouns?

Tags: adjectives, singular-vs-plural, nouns, as

I know this grammar structure. For example:

> I have as good *a voice* as you.

But I'm not sure if you can use a plural noun there. For example:

> I have as good *books* as you.

Or:

> They're not as glamorous *jobs* as people think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my ear, your examples are marginally grammatical, at best.

It would be more idiomatic to say it this way:

> I have books as good as yours.
>
> The jobs are not as glamorous as people think.
>
> They're not as glamorous as people think. <sup>strike  "jobs"</sup>
>
> They're not as glamorous, as jobs go, as people think.

The pattern is **as** {modifier} **as**.

Even the first sentence, which a percentage of native speakers would say, strikes other speakers as marginal.

> I have as good a voice as you.  I have as good a voice as you do. He has as good a voice as her.
>
> I have a voice as good as yours. He has a voice as good as hers.